# How to get a Blowfish encryption key

Tags: cryptography, key, encryption, blowfish

I have a bunch of messages in encrypted and decrypted form using [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) with the same key. Is there any way to get `key` out of those messages?

References to any algorithm or tool will be highly appreciated.
I have only basic knowledge of cryptography so please correct me if question is too broad and not specific enough.

Comment: Probably not -- but if you can do so, you'll be famous (at least among cryptographers) as the person who broke Blowfish using a known-plaintext attack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have many chances of getting the key. The only attacks that I see are:

- **leverage on flaws in the implementation of the encryption**. Blowfish is a block cipher, as such it encrypts only blocks of fixed size. In order to encrypt variable length files, you need a [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_of_operation) and a [padding scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29). In your post you do not tell which if these have been used for your files, but some of the few successful attacks against cryptography exploit wrong choice or implementations of these.
- if the key was derived from a password you can try to **guess the password**. In addition to the above, you also need to know [the algorithm that was used to derive the password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). You can also find in the Internet several [*dictionaries*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack), which are basically long lists of possible passwords. With some work you can write a program that checks several password per second. My experience says that if you are lucky and the password is in a dictionary you can probably find it in a few days.

For the sake of completeness, [**trying all the possible keys**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack) requires more than the life of the universe.

Comment: Note that Blowfish does have a set of 'weak keys' that are to be avoided but only if you don't use the full 16 rounds of encryption so this is a theoretical attack

Comment: Yes, errors in the implementation of Blowfish are unlikely. My answer applies to wrong implementations of modes of operations, like using multiple times the same IV.

Comment: "Some of the few successful attacks against cryptography" - there's no shortage of successful attacks in the crypto sphere. :)

Answer (score 6):

No, cryptography uses mathematical / binary functions to create (or rather, [transform](http://www.iusmentis.com/technology/encryption/crashcourse/introduction/)) the original data into encrypted information. If it stored the key within the message, it would be rendered useless.

Here is a reference for how the Blowfish Algorithm works: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29#The_algorithm).

Here is a reference on Symmetric-key cryptography, of which Blowfish is a part of (as a Symmetric Block Cipher): [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography#Symmetric-key_cryptography)

Comment: Thanks for the info about Blowfish!

Answer (score 1):

If those messages were stored in the file and the file is encrypted, you can write a script to do dictionary-based attack on those files. Of course, I am assuming that those texts are stored in the file and file is encrypted.

Sample:

```
$echo "Super secret" >> secret.txt; openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in secret.txt -out secret.enc -k password
```

you can reverse the process, by bruting it